# Reading large lz4 compressed JSON data set in Python 2.7

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, lz4

I need to analyze a large data set that is distributed as a lz4 compressed JSON file.

The compressed file is almost 1TB. I'd prefer not to uncompress it to disk due to cost. Each "record" in the dataset is very small, but it is obviously not feasible to read the entire data set into memory.

Any advice on how to iterate through records in this large lz4 compressed JSON file in Python 2.7?

Comment: You have to check what format lz4 file is. If it is a frame format, then it has multiple blocks, and you could go forward unpacking and processing block-by-block. If it is (single) block format, then a lot more work is required

Comment: Any hints on how to tell if it is frame or block format? This is the first time I've run across lz4.

Comment: Used in from c++ only - in the lz4 distribution there is a lz4 library which has frame analysis code, partial decoding etc. Might worth downloading and looking at: https://github.com/lz4/lz4/releases/tag/v1.8.0

Comment: This (http://python-lz4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lz4.frame.html) looks like right code to use

Answer (score 2):

As of version 0.19.1 of the [python lz4 bindings](https://github.com/python-lz4/python-lz4), there is full support for buffered IO provided. So, you should be able to do something like:

```
import lz4.frame
chunk_size = 128 * 1024 * 1024
with lz4.frame.open('mybigfile.lz4', 'r') as file:
    chunk = file.read(size=chunk_size)
    # Do stuff with this chunk of data.
```

which will read in data from the file at around 128 MB at a time.

Aside: I am the maintainer of the python lz4 package - please do file issues on the [project page](https://github.com/python-lz4/python-lz4) if you have problems with the package, or if something is not clear in the [documentation](http://python-lz4.readthedocs.io/en/stable/).

Comment: does not work for me unfortunately. getting `AttributeError: module 'lz4.frame' has no attribute 'open'`

Comment: I can only assume you have an old version. I assure you it's there. The current version is 1.1.0 - https://pypi.org/project/lz4/

Comment: i used conda install lz4, maybe its not updated on anaconda s servers?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't look like the conda package has been updated for quite some time.