# how to read an lz4 compressed file in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, lz4

I have a file like `stackunderflow.csv.lz4` and I want to load it in `Pandas` for processing.

I tried the naive `pd.read_csv()` without success. Can the great `Pandas` handle these types of compressed files?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Per [this StackOverFlow Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45966508/reading-large-lz4-compressed-json-data-set-in-python-2-7), you can use a 3rd party library to read in the data in chunks and then load that into your Pandas dataframe

`import lz4.frame
        chunk_size = 128 * 1024 * 1024
        with lz4.frame.open('mybigfile.lz4', 'r') as file:
            chunk = file.read(size=chunk_size)`

Comment: thanks but this does not load anything into pandas?

Comment: If you collect and combine all of the chunks, by the end of the while-loop, you will have your uncompressed CSV data which you can then load into Pandas

Comment: ok cool! perhaps can you add that to you code so that we have a complete answer? thanks!